# Observing buffered and group input in in Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a subject

```
  public ISubject<Price> PriceTicksSubject { get; }
```

This is buffered and subscribed as below

```
void DoSubscribe()
{
      PriceTicksSubject.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000)).
                Select(buffer => buffer.GroupBy(tick => tick.Key, (key, res) => res.Last())).
                ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default).Subscribe(x=> 
                        SendtoClients(x));    

}
```

What I want is the ability to send all items buffered and grouped in five seconds to be send as a single ienumerable to the clients. However, the code above calls SendToClients() multiple times(times the number of keys) every five seconds.

Any pointers on how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the buffered results in the `onNext` action:

```
void DoSubscribe()
{
    PriceTicksSubject.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000))
        .ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
        .Subscribe(bufferedPrices =>
        {
            SendtoClients(bufferedPrices.GroupBy(x => x.Key).Select(g => g.Last()).ToArray());
        });
}
```